# Changing key mapping of wrong model keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout, laptop-repair, remapping

The keyboard of my laptop broke recently so I ordered a new one and managed to swap it out, but when I turned the laptop on I noticed that a lot of keys were wrongly assigned or not even assigned at all (only the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key), some keys even apply to the same function (a lot of keys work as Play/Pause button).
Apparently I bought the wrong keyboard model, looks like for the laptop I have (Acer Nitro 5) multiple models have been sold, hence there are multiple keyboard models.

Is there any way to change the setting of which model of keyboard I’m using? Maybe somewhere in the BIOS?
Remapping the keys with software like Sharpkeys isn’t really an option since I also want to use an external keyboard and then I’d have to switch constantly between standard and custom mapping.

Comment: Can't you send it back and get a different one? Sounds like a lot of trouble which may have an easy fix.

Comment: The right model is somehow a lot more expensive then the one I got